# Реализация облака тэгов в SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3, xcode7

Суть вопроса :
Хочу реализовать tags (что-то типо облака тэгов)

Выглядит должно примерно так (как я вижу)

КолешнВьюКонтроллер В котором есть две секции:

1 секция - коллекшнВью в котором ячейками реализованы тэги

2 секция - коллекшнВью в которой выводится инфа

Вопрос таков, как мне правильно реализовать, что бы ячейки где будут теги подстраивались под размер слова(тега)
З.Ы. все пишется полностью на свифте сториборд не пользую!

Comment: вот это было немножко непонятно

Comment: да я сам не понимаю как правильно задать Вопрос

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko переделал вопрос )))

Comment: короче надо по данному строингу и известному размеру фонта оппределить минимальный размер вью, чтоб оно поместилось?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ага. чтоб по длине слова было облачко за ним следующее тоже по длине и т.д в ряд.

Comment: у `NSString` есть вот такой метод https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrectwithsize?language=objc